# Executing Junit Tests in ant - noclassdeffounderror wrong name

Tags: junit, ant, javac, build.xml

I'm trying to execute a few junit test suits with ant.

Here's my folder structure

- bin
- lib
- src
- test
- build.xml

First of all I compile all files in source location, later on java files in test folder.

Whole structure of test folder (compiled .class files) are saved in bin folder which looks like this inside.

bin-test-alltests
        |
        -suites - SetupSuite.class
               - StartSuite.class

in *allTests* folder are tests that are used in suites in *suites* folder

I'm trying to start those suites but constantly I've got an error:

**ant junit java.lang.noclassdeffounderror wrong name**

I'm pretty sure that's something wrong with the class path but I don't know what. I've tried to changed

`<test name="SetupSuite"/>` 
to

```
<test name="SetupSuite.class"/>
```

and I get another error:

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SetupSuite.class**

Here's my build.xml file

```
<project name="MyTest" basedir=".">

    <!--Common properties -->
    <property name="src.dirname" value="src" />
    <property name="test.dirname" value="test" />
    <property name="lib.dirname" value="lib" />
    <property name="bin.dirname" value="bin" />
    <property name="src.encoding" value="utf8" />
    <property name="src.version" value="1.7" />
    <property environment="env" />

    <!-- Paths for MyTest -->
    <property name="MyTest.dir" value="${basedir}" />
    <property name="MyTest.src.dir" value="${MyTest.dir}\${src.dirname}" />
    <property name="MyTest.test.dir" value="${MyTest.dir}\${test.dirname}" />
    <property name="MyTest.dest.dir" value="${MyTest.dir}\${bin.dirname}" />
    <property name="MyTest.lib.dir" value="${MyTest.dir}\${lib.dirname}" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="${MyTest.lib.dir}\junit.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${MyTest.test.dir}\test\suites\" />
    </path>

    <target name="compile-MyTest-src" >
        <myjavac srcdir="${MyTest.src.dir}" destdir="${MyTest.dest.dir}" classpath="{MyTest.lib.dir}\junit.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile-MyTest-test" depends="compile-MyTest-src">
        <path id='libs'>
            <fileset dir= "${MyTest.lib.dir}\" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </path>
    <myjavac srcdir="${MyTest.test.dir}\" destdir="${MyTest.dest.dir}" classpathref = 'libs'/>
    </target>

    <target name="execute-tests" depends="compile-MyTest-src,compile-MyTest-test">
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="yes">
        <formatter type = "brief" usefile = "false" />
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
            <test name="SetupSuite"/>
        </junit>
    </target>   

   <!-- General compiler settings -->
    <presetdef name="myjavac">
        <javac classpathref="classpath" debug="on" includeantruntime="false" encoding="${src.encoding}" source="${src.version}" target="${src.version}" />
    </presetdef>

</project>
```

Comment: Please show us the problematic test suite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set test name to [full name](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) of your SetupSuite:

```
<test name="alltests.suites.SetupSuite"/>
```

Comment: package in this suite looks like this - package test.suites;

I've tried with     <test name="test.suites.SetupSuite"/> and I get **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SetupSuite.class**

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to add hamcrest-core-1.3.jar file to classpath